# Change SSH default host

Tags: ssh, terminal

I am trying to use SSH but for whatever host I pass in It defaults to one from AWS that I used months ago. I have looked in the ssh_config file and did not see any aliases either. Here are some examples of what I mean.

```
ssh xxx.xx.x.xx
```

returns

```
ssh: connect to host ec2-x-xx-xx-xxx.ca-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

No matter what x is, It keeps giving this message.

I am using zsh on mac.

Comment: I'll hazard a guess and say you have a shell file somewhere called `ssh` which  is being run, and in it, it connects to the AWS system, `which ssh`  should tell you if this is the case, assuming Mac has `which`.

Comment: @Bib do have this shell file, should I just remove it?

Comment: If that's what it does, then I think yes. An easier way to connect the loooonnngggg host name of AWS, is to put a shorter one in /etc/hosts. You could always specify the full pathname to ssh, and that should work.

Comment: Adding a host alias to `~/.ssh/config` is also an option.

Comment: I dont have a ~/.ssh/config file, also @Bib Im not able to read the file so i cant tell, it it encoded.

Comment: @Jake You can create one.

Comment: What is the output of `type ssh`?